# "...смутит леди или джентльмена, читающих/его эту книгу..."

Tags: причастия, единственное-множественное-число, или

> Вор бежал на север и, оказавшись в безопасности, стал швырять деньги направо и налево, тратя их на непристойные радости, чьё описание, вне всякого сомнения, смутит леди или джентльмена, **читающих** эту книгу, и поэтому я опущу подробности.

Правильно ли используется слово "читающих", или же должно быть "читающего"?

У Розенталя я нашел такое [правило](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm) (§190, п. 2):

> сказуемое ставится во множественном числе, если возникает необходимость согласования в роде и подлежащие принадлежат к разному грамматическому роду, например: ...Ни одно государство или группа государств не должны получить военное преимущество; Действие или признак субъекта (подлежащего) выражены сказуемым; Статья в целом или отрывок из нее представили бы интерес для читателей сборника.

Применимо ли это правило здесь? В нем не говорится о причастиях, но причастие – это форма глагола.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С одной стороны, союз «или» соединяет взаимоисключающие вещи. «…Смутит леди или джентльмена…» — смутит кого-то одного, а не обоих. Если б было «…смутит леди и джентльмена, читающих эту книгу…», тогда точно «читающих», т. е. обоих читающих. «Или» значит кого-то одного, поэтому хочется сказать «читающего».

Однако у [Розенталя](https://info.wikireading.ru/69463):

> 2. Определение ставится в форме множественного числа: <…> 2) если определение постпозитивно (даже при наличии разделительного союза
>    между определяемыми словами); например: *Мелкие повреждения кожи
>    смазываются настойкой **йода или бриллиантовой зеленью,
>    предохраняющими** от гнойничковых заболеваний*.

Поэтому, получается, что правильно: «…смутит леди или джентльмена, читающих эту книгу…».

P. S.
Вы подобрали не то правило; «читающих» — это не сказуемое.

> Одиночное полное причастие и причастный оборот в предложении являются
> определениями… [[uzdevumi.lv](https://www.uzdevumi.lv/p/russkii-iazyk/7-klass/sintaksicheskaia-funktciia-prichastii-10280/re-03dc7595-78f1-43e2-ab1c-1bff813106f8)]

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, "читающих", иначе получится отдельно леди и отдельно читающий джентльмен. Даже нет смысла ссылаться на правило, хватает логики.